# Combine redirect with serve files

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have a couple of server blocks that are not playing nice with each other and I want to serve the files from the `.well-known/` folder but also redirect to `https` when they are not from the `.well-known/` folder

How can I make one server block that redirects but also serve some files?

sites-enabled/block1

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.html;
  server_name _;

  location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

sites-enabled/block2

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com cdn.example.com subdomain.example.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all three `server` blocks with this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location /.well-known {
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Using a `default_server` for port 80 will redirect all requests to the similarly named `https` server, unless the URI begins with `/.well-known`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more.

Comment: Your idea is great, but wouldn't be `location ~ /.well-known` instead of `location /.well-known`?

Comment: The `~` is used for a regular expression. The well known directory begins with `/.well-known`, so a prefix location is sufficient (and more efficient).

Comment: And the `allow all` ? Isn't all the files going to be hidden since the parent is hidden too?

Comment: `allow all` is the default in the absence of any other access control directives.